# WebClient not parsing response to list of json objects

Tags: java, spring-boot, webclient

I am trying to call the API that returns a JSON array.

For the webClient i have something like

```java
webClient
      .get()
      .uri("/")
      .retrieve()
      .bodyToFlux(JSONObject.class)
      .collectList()
      .block();
```

and my return type is `List<JSONObject>`
I am using `JsonObject` because we don't care about what the data is as long as it is a valid JSON array.

and the sample response from the API is

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "test_2"
    }
]
```

but getting

Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "id" (class org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.json.JSONObject), not marked as ignorable (0 known properties: ])

---

Do I need any class which has `JsonObject` like a field or something or am I doing something wrong here?

thanks in advance.

Comment: You should create a POJO class for each JSONObject, and try to retrieve the `List<Pojo>`

Comment: It's trying to map ```id``` and ```name``` to fields of the ```JSONObject``` which don't exist. You could instead use ```LinkedHashMap``` which is the standard for Jackson.

Comment: In `bodyToFlux()` you should pass the Pojo class's class object. JSONObject does not have any field like "id" and "name"

Comment: ok so i should create a pojo class with `JsonObject someObject` and then have it as `bodyToFlux(Pojo.class)`, @Shantanu

Comment: Correct. That should work.

Comment: its still throwing error saying `unrecognized field`, 
I have my class with this `public class response() { JSONObject someObject; }` with other things like constructors.

Comment: Now using as `bodyToMono(String.class)`, then creating a json array from the string result. its working now